# Why am I getting an error message when trying to run manage.py?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cmd

Getting a list of errors in cmd prompt (Windows 8) when trying to run manage.py.
I am trying to follow this tutorial:  http://wiki.thinkhole.org/howto:django_on_windows/
I am a little less than half way down the tutorial page.
Can someone please tell me what is going wrong and how to get back on track?
I am trying to get django installed on my computer so i can create a web page with python.
The actual command prompt error log is this:

```
C:\Py\Scripts\testproject>manage.py runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Py\Scripts\testproject\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, i
n execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, i
n execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in ru
n_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in ex
ecute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130,
 in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 18
8, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 17
7, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 15
9, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_m
odule
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 3, in <m
odule>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py", line 7, in <mo
dule>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 129
, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "C:\Py\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings

C:\Py\Scripts\testproject>
```

Comment: That tutorial seems *really* old. Are you really using Python 2.5 as it says there?

Comment: i am using python 2.6 because most of the tutorials and info out there seems to match the syntax and i get less error messages

Comment: Python 2.6 is really outdated. Please use either 2.7 or 3.4. And follow the official Django tutorial. Before following 3rd party tutorials, check the version numbers and the date.